# Video rendering in WebView lags

Tags: android, webview, android-7.0-nougat, android-tv

I am using webview to render a page having videos, but the videos on the page keep lagging. But the same page works very well in chrome.

I have set **android:hardwareAccelerated="true"** in manifest file and also have added **webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())** to my java file but has not helped much (the rendering is better but still has some lagging). Is there any way to use the chrome features in webview so that lagging of video can be removed.

I am using the following: -
Android 7 (Nougat) in Android TV player.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: By chance, do you had a textview marquee in parallel?

Comment: Did you get to work Video run smoother in a WebView?